# Matplotlib with Tkinter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to build up a program using Tkinter and Matplotlib which the user can select among several functions thorough a checkbutton and plotting the selected function using a plot button. The resulted plots must be stored into a tabs of a Tkinter notebook, I mean, every time the plot button is clicked, the generated graph must appear in a new tab. For this aim, I have created two classes, the first one creates the GUI and the second one makes the graphs. I am facing two problems, when I imported the Matplotlib charts into a tab of the Tkinter notebook, the toolbar is not imported, all what I got was the image of the function but I really need the toolbar with the cursor position tool. Moreover, every time I clicked the plot button, the next graph is overlapped with the old one, it is supposed that the old graph have been destroyed. Finally, if I dont import the matplotlib charts into a Tkinter notebook, the programs plots correctly the first time but when I clicked the plot button a second time, all what I got was a blank canvas. I have tried a lot of things but I cannot figured out what is going on here.
I know there are many problems but I would appreciate a lot your help.
Thank you in advance.

GUI:

```
from stack2 import *
import numpy as np
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *


class Gui:

    # Attributes of the class

    # Array to store the objects
    objects = np.array([])

    # Dictionary to store the data
    data = {
        "x": np.array(
            [
                0,
                2.216666667,
                4.216666667,
                6.216666667,
                23.48333333,
                70.83333333,
                143.8333333,
            ]
        ),
        "y": np.array([0, 0.3812, 0.59375, 0.6176, 0.6165, 0.39845, 0.2692]),
    }

    # Constructor function
    def __init__(self, title, width, height, foreground, background):

        # Attributes of the instance
        self.root = Tk()  # Root
        self.title = title  # Title
        self.height = height  # Height
        self.width = width  # Width
        self.foreground = foreground  # Foreground
        self.background = background  # Background color

    # Method of the class

    # Function for setting the style of each button
    def buttonStyle(self):

        # Creating object style
        buttonStyle = ttk.Style()

        # Setting style
        buttonStyle.configure("TButton", foreground="black", background="blue", width=5)

        return "TButton"

    # Function for setting the style of each frame
    def frameStyle(self):

        # Creating object style
        frameStyle = ttk.Style()

        # Setting style
        frameStyle.configure("TFrame", background=self.background)

        return "TFrame"

    # Function for setting the style of each frame
    def notebookStyle(self):

        # Creating object style
        notebookStyle = ttk.Style()

        # Setting style
        notebookStyle.configure("TNotebook", background=self.background)

        return "TNotebook"

    # Function for setting the style of each checkbutton
    def checkButtonStyle(self):

        # Creating object style
        checkButtonStyle = ttk.Style()

        # Setting style
        checkButtonStyle.configure(
            "TCheckbutton", foreground="black", background="white"
        )

        return "TCheckbutton"

    # Function for creating the appareance of Gui
    def appareance(self):

        # Setting tittle
        self.root.title(self.title)

        # Size of screen
        self.root.geometry(str(self.width) + "x" + str(self.height))

        # Changing background color
        self.root.configure(bg=self.background)

        # Creating a notebook
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root, style=self.notebookStyle())
        self.notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, pady=15)

        # Creating frame for Gui
        self.frameGui = ttk.Frame(self.notebook, style=self.frameStyle())
        self.frameGui.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        # Adding frame to tabs of notebook
        self.notebook.add(self.frameGui, text="Data")

    # Function to create a menu
    def menu(self):

        # Creating main menu
        mainMenu = Menu(self.root)

        # Setting main menu
        self.root.config(menu=mainMenu)

        plot = Menu(mainMenu, tearoff=FALSE)

        # Adding submenus to main menu
        mainMenu.add_cascade(label="Plot", menu=plot)

        # Adding command to submenus
        plot.add_command(label="Functions", command=self.secondMenu)

    # Function to create the second menu
    def secondMenu(self):

        # Creating a second window
        secondWindow = Toplevel(self.root, background=self.background)

        # Size of screen
        secondWindow.geometry("400x200")

        # Getting the coordinates of root window
        coordinateX = self.root.winfo_x()
        coordinateY = self.root.winfo_y()

        # Positioning the left upper toplevel window
        secondWindow.geometry("+%d+%d" % (coordinateX + self.width, coordinateY))

        # Creating first checkbutton
        self.firstVariable = IntVar()

        checkbuttonFirst = ttk.Checkbutton(
            secondWindow,
            text="Function",
            style=self.checkButtonStyle(),
            variable=self.firstVariable,
        )
        # Showing in screen
        checkbuttonFirst.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, sticky="EW")

        # Creating button to plot the selected function
        buttonPlotFunction = ttk.Button(
            secondWindow, text="Plot", style=self.buttonStyle(), command=self.plot
        )
        # Showing in screen
        buttonPlotFunction.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10)

    # Function to plot the pharmacokinetics
    def plot(self):

        # Deleting each object
        for object in self.objects:

            del object

        # Creating frame for Pharmakinetics plot
        framePlot = ttk.Frame(self.notebook, style=self.frameStyle())
        framePlot.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        # Adding frame to tabs of notebook
        self.notebook.add(framePlot, text="Plot")

        # Creating an object from classPharmakinetics
        objPlot = Plot(
            framePlot,
            "Test plot",
            self.background,
            "x",
            "y",
            self.data,
        )

        self.objects = np.append(self.objects, objPlot)

        if self.firstVariable.get() == 1:
            objPlot.plot()

    # Function for calling each function from the class
    def gui(self):

        self.appareance()

        self.menu()

        # Creating infinite loop to show in screen
        self.root.mainloop()
```

Plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
from tkinter import *


class Plot:

    # Attributes of the class

    # Creating the canvas and the axis
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Constructor function
    def __init__(self, root, title, background, xLabel, yLabel, data):

        self.root = root  # Root
        self.title = title  # Title
        self.background = background  # Background color
        self.xLabel = xLabel  # Label of axis X
        self.yLabel = yLabel  # Label of axis Y
        self.data = data  # Dictionary to store the data

        # Data to evaluate the functions
        self.dataRange = np.linspace(
            self.data["x"][0],
            self.data["x"][len(self.data["x"]) - 1],
            100,
            endpoint=True,
        )

    # Double exponential function
    def doubleExponential(self, time, A, B, C):

        return A * (np.exp(-B * time) - np.exp(-C * time))

    # Function to plot the double exponential function
    def plot(self):

        # Adding the function to fit as the Model
        model = Model(self.doubleExponential)

        # Initializing the parameters
        params = model.make_params(A=0.5, B=0.005, C=0.5)

        # Getting the fitting data
        dataFitting = model.fit(self.data["y"], params, time=self.data["x"])

        # Plotting the fitted function using the obtained parameters
        self.ax.plot(
            self.dataRange,
            self.doubleExponential(
                self.dataRange,
                dataFitting.params["A"].value,
                dataFitting.params["B"].value,
                dataFitting.params["C"].value,
            ),
            "-",
            label="Fit",
        )

        # Inserting matplotlib charts into canvas
        matplotlib_gui = self.root

        # Creating the Tkinter canvas containing the Matplotlib figure
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=matplotlib_gui)
        canvas.draw()

        # Placing the canvas on the Tkinter window
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

        # Creating the Matplotlib toolbar
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, matplotlib_gui)
        toolbar.update()

        # Placing the toolbar on the Tkinter window
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

Main:

```
from stack1 import *

# Main features of a GUI
title = "Plot"
width = 500
height = 500
foreground = "black"
background = "white"

# Creating an object from classGUI
a = Gui(title, width, height, foreground, background)

a.gui()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue of importing the tool bar was produced due to inserting the frame instead of the root window, as the second argument of
`NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, matplotlib_gui)`. Apparently, the second argument must be the root window.

Comment: On the other hand, I am still have the issue of the overlapping of the graph.